# Firefox 37.0.2 not opening (removing firefox did not help) runing ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: firefox

Opening firefox through the desktop icon will show the loading cursor, but a few seconds later it will stop loading and never open a firefox window. It is possible to load firefox from the terminal, but only in safe mode. I get the following error when attempting to load in terminal:

```
(process:26701): GLib-CRITICAL **:g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size== 0' failed
```

I have found several pages suggesting the following will fix this problem:

```
chown -hR YOUR_USER .gnome2/

chown -hR YOUR_USER .gnome2_private/
```

however, this did not help, I got the following error:

```
chown: cannot access '.gnome2/': No such file or directory

chown: cannot access '.gnome2/private': No such file or directory
```

Any suggestions? I have removed firefox and re-installed in terminal, but the same error still occurs.

Comment: In many cases, if an application still doesn't work as expected after a reinstall, it is the local files that are corrupted. Please try removing (-renaming temporarily) `~/.mozilla`, log out/in and try again.

Comment: still new to Ubuntu, what would the command line be in terminal?

Comment: If you are new to Ubuntu, I'd just remove it "visually" by making `~/.mozilla` visible (in your home directory) by pressing Ctrl+H :).

Comment: ok, the directory has been renamed, I then re-installed firefox, but it is still not launcing from the desktop icon. I removed the application and reloaded it from the Ubuntu Software Center

Comment: I had missed the logging out/in step, thank you. It is now working properly.

Comment: Cool! Would you mind if I posted it as an answer?

Comment: *If* the answer solves your issue, like you mentioned in a comment, please mark it as accepted (below the up/down arrows on the left). Otherwise it will re-appear as unanswered...

Answer (score 2):

#### Most likely:

In far most cases, if an application still does not work after a (complete) reinstall, its local settings files or profile(s) are corrupted for some reason.

In this case, the `firefox` local files are in `~/.mozilla`

#### What to do:

You should either remove the directory `~/.mozilla` or, if it contains valuable settings, first try to rename it. Then (best before running `Firefox` again), log out and back in.

#### .desktop files

Another option, although not very likely in this case, is an outdated or otherwise incorrect local `.desktop` file in `~/usr/share/applications`. This can especially be the case if an application is updated to a newer version.