# Firefox is not starting on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: firefox

At first I tried running Firefox normally on Ubuntu 14.04 after a power cut that occurred while the computer was on suspend mode, and Firefox didn't start. I followed [these instructions](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2227428) by renaming Firefox, but still no result. I tried updating, removing, re installing and nothing works. The error from running it from the terminal is as follows:

```
(process:12919): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
(firefox:12919): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::sm-connect after class was initialised
(firefox:12919): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::show-crash-dialog after class was initialised
(firefox:12919): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::display after class was initialised
(firefox:12919): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::default-icon after class was initialised
Could not create gnome accelerators directory `/home/nautilus/.gnome2/accels': Permission denied
```

Comment: I am pretty sure this is helping:  http://askubuntu.com/a/617459/72216 In most cases, local files are damaged. OP there mentioned it was the solution, in spite of not accepting (therefore I can't mark it as a dupe :) )

Comment: Did it, Removed the /.mozilla folder, and reinstalled mozilla

Comment: It works? if not, don't forget *to log out/in* after removing the local folder.

Comment: @JacobVlijm done, and checked, same error results (process:13759): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed

Comment: @OsamaSalama that message is completely normal when you run Firefox from the terminal.

Comment: um, `/home/nautilus/` ? is that your username , nautilus ?

Comment: @Serg the latest coment, it sais: (process:13759): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed That's normal

Comment: @JacobVlijm I didn't say anything about that - I know it's normal.

Comment: @Serg Ah, sorry, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try typing this at the command line: (assuming your username is nautilus)

```
sudo chown nautilus /home/nautilus/.gnome2
```

You will be asked to provide your password.  This is the password you use to login.

Comment: I don't know why you got downvoted here.  I gave you a +1 as you fixed what he was looking for.   Good straight forward answer.  :)

Comment: Is there any way to tell who downvoted me I wonder...  I was kind of wondering myself.